# python - how to have video file(data) into list?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, video, udp

I am doing a project on media (more like a video conferencing).
The problem is , although I am able to send text/string data from one peer to another, I am still not sure about video files.
Using gstreamer, I am able to capture video stream from my webcam  and doing the encoding/coding (H.264) , I am able to write the video stream into actual mp4 contanier directly using a file sink

Now my problem is, I am not sure on reading the video files as it contains both audio and video streams, convert into transmission stream to transmit it using packets
(I am able to send a very small jpeg file although).
I am using socket module and implementing UDP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to send a video(with audio) to a peer in the network, you would better use RTP(Real time Transfer Protocol) which works on top of UDP. RTP provides feature of timestamps and profile which help you syncronize the audio and video sent through two ports.